# Objective C converting NSDictionary valueForKeyPath into a string

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary that I am trying to get some strings out of.  The name of the dictionary is called tweets.  I can get the user name and tweet by doing the following.

```
 NSDictionary *tweet = self.detailItem;
 NSString *username = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];
 NSString *tweetText = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
```

If I NSLog the results I get; username is "person's username" and tweetText is "person's tweet."  These are both NSString that I can manipulate.

However, I also need to get the actual URL from the tweet, not the shortened one.  So I have found it in the dictionary with valueForKeyPath.  I need this as a string and have tried the following.

```
NSString *url = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"entities.urls.display_url"];
```

I can NSLog this as well and I get the proper information.  But I think it comes out as an Array?  The NSLog looks like this..  url is ( "url goes here" ).  With the brackets and quotes.  This is not a string like the others.  I am assuming it is because of the valueForKeyPath.  When I tried to use url hasPrefix, it doesn't like that and mentions you can't have hasPrefix with and array.  But I also tried to use multiple objectForKey with entities, urls, and display_url.  But this does not work.  Is there any way to get my entry into a string format.  I have looked over some SO questions and on the web, but can't find anything that is useful for me.  Any help will by much appreciated.  Thanks for your time

Comment: You can figure out the type by dumping [url class] to a %@ in an NSLog. Use the debugger with a breakpoint in XCode or Appcode. It will easily reveal the structure of your dictionary.

Comment: @NickWeaver, Thanks for the help.  I just did this and yes it is an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Twitter's documentation on entities](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities), `entities` is a dictionary and `urls` is an array of dictionaries.

When you perform `... valueForKeyPath:@"entities.urls.display_url"]` you do the same thing as `... valueForKey:@"entities"] valueForKey:@"urls] valueForKey:@"display_url"]`.

Per [`NSDictionary`'s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/valueForKey%3a), its `valueForKey:` returns the same thing as `objectForKey:` if — as in this case — the key in question doesn't start with an @.

So the `entities` part of `valueForKeyPath:` returns an array of objects.

Per [`NSArray`'s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey%3a), its `valueForKey:` returns an array comprised of the result of calling `valueForKey:` on each object in the array individually.

Given that each thing in the `entities` array is a dictionary, what you therefore get back is an array of the `display_url` key for every entity in the tweet.

So I think your problem is that you expect to get "*the* actual URL from the tweet" (emphasis added). Tweets may contain arbitrary many links outward, not merely one — entities represent ranges of characters with special meanings like links, hashtags and similar. So you end up with an array rather than a single value.

Comment: Tommy, Thanks so much.  Getting it as an array and then turning that into a string worked.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

The keyPath entities.urls.display_url traverse an array of arrays and flattens that to return an array of display_urls.  If you were confident that there would be only one url within that hierarchy you could use

```
NSString *url = [[tweet valueForKeyPath:@"entities.urls.display_url"] lastObject];
```

If there are multiple entities with URLs you may have to traverse the entities and urls to determine the URL in which you are interested.  Or you may be able to use firstObject  if what you are really looking for is entities.urls.[0].display_url

Comment: KHansenSF, thanks for your time.  I ended up using the array form and turning that into a string.  However, I will try your too!  Thanks.